# ComboBox SelectedItem Not Changing

Tags: c#, winforms

Edit: I am using window forms

So, I want to change a value of NumericUpDown if the selected value in combo box changes.

I placed a data table items with the columns ID, itemName, itemPrice and Stock and set the DisplayMember property to itemName.

I used this code:

```
cmb.DisplayMember = "itemName";
cmb.DataSource = items;
```

Then to get the whole row of the selected item I used

```
DataRow dataRow = ((DataRowView)cmbItems.SelectedItem).Row;
```

The problem is that in the UI, the combo box's selected item does not changes no matter what I do but the value of the selected item changes.

Like this.
[image]

I first thought that my unit is just lagging but its not. How do I fix this?

Comment: How do you change the selected item of your ComboBox? I guess you don't use the ComboBox but write something in the first TextBox, right?

Comment: I would guess that you're setting the selected item value manually in the code somewhere, likely sometime after the ItemChanged event.  The combobox changes the value and then immediately changes it back before the UI has a chance to refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to check if the combobox will get the selected item when you make your option.

```
dbConn.Open();// this allows you to edit the database

string sql = "Select * from database1";

SqlCommand dbComm = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConn);

SqlDataAdapter dbAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(dbComm);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();

dbAdapter.Fill(dt);

cmbDescription.DataSource = dt;

cmbDescription.DisplayMember = "itemName";

cmbDescription.ValueMember = "Enter the column name here";

cmbDescription.Text = "";

cmbDescription.Items.Add(dt);

cdbConn.Close(); //close connection to save all your inputs,calculations to the database
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that my code is very confusing and the system seem to be having problems while executing, I've rewritten the whole code for this window form and it is working now.